# boost::priority_queue not compiling

Tags: visual-c++, boost, priority-queue

Created a boost::priority_queue with my comparison operation defined. Here is how my priority_queue looks,

```
boost::heap::priority_queue<myObject*, boost::heap::compare<myObjectPtrCompare> > max_heap;
```

My comparison is defined as,

```
struct myObjectPtrCompare
{
    bool operator()(const myObject* lhs, const myObject* rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs->getTime() < rhs->getTime());
    }
};
```

I have used it as,

```
myObject* obj1 = static_cast<myObject*>(base1);
```

'base1' is an object of class 'myBase'(base class of myObject)

myObject and getTime() within it used for comparision are defined as,

```
class myObject : public myBase {
    Time getTime() const { return time; }
.
.
. 
...
}
```

Compiling this gives me this error,

```
c:\Projects\pq_test.cpp(27): error C2662: 'void boost::heap::priority_queue<myObject*,boost::heap::compare<myObjectPtrCompare>,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_>::push(myObject *const &)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const boost::heap::priority_queue<myObject *,boost::heap::compare<myObjectPtrCompare>,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_>' to 'boost::heap::priority_queue<myObject *,boost::heap::compare<myObjectPtrCompare>,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_> &'
1>          Conversion loses qualifiers
```

Using Visual Studio 2013 C++. I understand that I am doing something wrong with const correctness, but I am not able to figure out what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

TIA!

EDIT1:
@Maxim Egorushkin : Thanks!
I saw that,

```
myObject* obj1 = static_cast<myObject*>(base1);
```

is in a function which is a const function whose signature is,

```
void workOnObj(myBase* base1) const;
```

So, I changed my definition of my priority_queue to const as,

```
const boost::heap::priority_queue<Container*, boost::heap::compare<ContainerPtrCompare> > max_heap;
```

and expected that the error would go away, but it still has the same error.

Comment: Where is the push coming from? Show the relevant code, as is.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the code calls non-const `priority_queue::push` on a `const priority_queue` object. You need a non-const `priority_queue` object to be able to call `push` on it.

Answer (score 0):

In cases of trouble, *always* post a self-contained example. Your sample doesn't even show a `push` operation, so it cannot possibly generate the error message shown.

Here's a simplistic example showing your types that works, so you can see what you're doing differently:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20e23259e8e53721)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/heap/priority_queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

static std::mt19937 s_rng { std::random_device{}() };

struct myObject {
    int _time = s_rng() % 1024;
    int getTime() const { return _time; }
};

struct myObjectPtrCompare {
    bool operator()(myObject const *lhs, myObject const *rhs) const { return lhs->getTime() < rhs->getTime(); }
};

int main() {
    boost::heap::priority_queue<myObject *, boost::heap::compare<myObjectPtrCompare> > max_heap;

    for (auto i = 0u; i < s_rng() % 100; ++i)
        max_heap.push(new myObject{});

    while (max_heap.size()) {
        std::cout << "time: " << max_heap.top()->getTime() << "\n";
        delete max_heap.top();
        max_heap.pop();
    }
}
```

It uses random data each time, but will print something similar to:

```
time: 1012
time: 994
time: 957
time: 904
time: 889
time: 872
time: 566
time: 460
time: 378
time: 310
time: 254
time: 243
time: 22
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. I should have added a non-working example. Now fixed the issue I had initially and it was because I was trying to add to the priority_queue in a const function. Now, I have warnings(we treat them as errors) when I compile it,

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. I should have added a non-working example. Now fixed the issue I had initially and it was because I was trying to add to the priority_queue in a const function. Now, I have warnings(we treat them as errors) when I compile it as,

1>          c:\Projects\priority_queue_example.h(193) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::heap::priority_queue<myObject *,boost::heap::compare<myObjectPtrCompare>,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_>' being compiled

Comment: You still didn't add any code, and to make things worse you are complaining about error messages that you are not showing. Why should I spend time on this? I'm not psychic anyways.

Comment: Sigh. I've seen [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725269/warnings-in-boostpriority-queue) (the answer is correct). Was this answer helpful in any way? You cannot blame others if your question is incomplete, and by not editing this question to be complete, you have made people's time effectively wasted. Please also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work