# Warnings in boost::priority_queue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, warnings, priority-queue

When I try to build "priority_queue_example.cpp" it get these warnings(and so errors) pointing to  "priority_queue_example.h" on the line where my priority_queue is declared. The warnings are,

```
1>  priority_queue_example.cpp
1>c:\Projects\lib\boost\boost\heap\detail\stable_heap.hpp(102): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>c:\Projects\lib\boost\boost\heap\detail\stable_heap.hpp(102): warning 
C4100: 'rhs' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>          c:\Projects\lib\boost\boost\heap\detail\stable_heap.hpp(102) : while compiling class template member function 'boost::heap::detail::size_holder<false,size_t>::size_holder(const boost::heap::detail::size_holder<false,size_t> &)'
1>          c:\Projects\lib\boost\boost\heap\detail\stable_heap.hpp(189) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::heap::detail::size_holder<false,size_t>::size_holder(const boost::heap::detail::size_holder<false,size_t> &)' being compiled
1>          c:\Projects\lib\boost\boost\heap\detail\stable_heap.hpp(151) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::heap::detail::size_holder<false,size_t>' being compiled
1>          c:\Projects\lib\boost\boost\heap\priority_queue.hpp(65) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::heap::detail::heap_base<T,myObjectPtrCompare,false,unsigned __int64,false>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=myObject *
1>          ]
1>          c:\Projects\priority_queue_example.h(193) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::heap::priority_queue<myObject *,boost::heap::compare<myObjectPtrCompare>,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_>' being compiledcompare<ObjectPtrCompare>,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void
```

My priority_queue is declared as,

```
mutable boost::heap::priority_queue<myObject*, boost::heap::compare<myObjectPtrCompare> > hp;
```

I'm not sure what this means. Can I fix this?

This is my comparison class defined,

```
struct myObjectPtrCompare
{   
    bool operator()(const myObject* lhs, const myObject* rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs->getProp() < rhs->getProp());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Boost is not warning-free with /W4. That means that there could be spurious warnings, even if your code is corect.

You can disable specific warnings as specified in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings

> 1. In Solution Explorer, choose the project or source file in which you want to suppress warnings.
> 2. On the menu bar, choose View, Property Pages.
> 3. Choose the Configuration Properties category, choose the C/C++ category, and then choose the Advanced page.
> 4. Perform one of the following steps:
>
>    - In the Disable Specific Warnings box, specify the error codes of the warnings that you want to suppress, separated by a semicolon.
>    - In the Disable Specific Warnings box, choose Edit to display more options.
> 5. Choose the OK button, and then rebuild the solution.